# "A/The guide to" in a book's title

Tags: grammar, articles

Which article is correct for a book's title and why? For example:

- A/The guide to Java Programming
- A/The guide to Project Management

Comment: I would probably say 'A guide to...', but don't know the reason why I would say that.

Comment: You use the indefinite article, because there are many guides for those topics, unless you want to single yours out as somehow special, for example "The *definitive* guide to ..."